# How to describe ordered pairs without the usual notation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Extension by definition allows the introduction of a new function symbol once the existence and uniqueness has been shown, for example [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extension_by_definitions) says "Let $T$ be a first order-theory (with equality) and $\phi(y,x_1,...x_n)$ a formula of $T$ such that $y,x_1,...,x_n$ are distinct and include the variables free in $\phi(y,x_1,...,x_n)$. Assume that we can prove $$\forall x_1,...,x_n \exists ! y \phi(y,x_1,...,x_n)$$ in $T$. Form a new first-order theory $T'$ from $T$ by adding a new n-ary function symbol $f$, the logical axioms featuring the symbol $f$ and the new axiom $$\forall x_1,...,x_n \phi(f(x_1,...,x_n),x_1,...,x_n),$$ called the defining axiom of $f$."

This is done for example when introducing the union of sets, introducing the symbol $\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i$ for sets $A_i, i \in I$ or even the set notation $\{...\}$. I think this is also done when introducing ordered pairs. Let $X,Y$ be sets, then for all $x \in X, y \in Y$ there exists an object $(x,y)$ satisfying $$(x,y)=(x',y') \iff x=x' \wedge y=y'.$$ However, here we already introduced a new symbol, namely "$(-,-)$". How would one introduce ordered pairs without this symbol? More precisely, I would like to proceed as follows. For all $x \in X,y \in Y$ there exists an object $z$ such that it satisfies the property. Then we can denote this object by $(x,y)$. However, I don't know how one could write this property in terms of $z$. Furthermore, do we know that ordered pairs are unique? The notion of ordered pairs that is modelled in set theory is unique, however, is this enough? One could for example assume axioms regarding ordered pairs, which are not modelled by sets but solely based on those axioms. Can I also introduce these symbols there?

**Analogy to make the question more precise** Suppose that $A,B$ are sets. Then there exists a unique set $C$ such that for all $x$ we have $$x \in C \iff x \in A \wedge x \in B.$$ Once we have proven this we can introduce the symbol $A \cap B$. The difference to the ordered pair situation is that I did not introduce a symbol depending on $A,B$ but I used the symbol $C$ to denote this object. I want this for ordered pairs as well, but I am stuck doing so.

Comment: Minor point, but in your last paragraph your $\wedge$ should be $\vee$ (or your $\cup$ should be $\cap$).

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of coding ordered pairs in set theory for instance you could define $(x,y)$ to be $\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}$ or you could define it to be $\{x,\{x,y\}\}$ in both cases you can prove in ZFC set theory that $(x,y)=(x’,y’) \iff x=x’ \land y=y’$.

Comment: Elaborating on this answer for the OP: you have to **pick an implementation** to use. For example, the Kuratowski ordered pair $$\langle x,y\rangle_K:=\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}$$ corresponds to the formula $$\varphi_K(x,y,z):\equiv \forall a[a\in z\leftrightarrow(\forall b(b\in a\leftrightarrow b=x))\vee(\forall b(b\in a\leftrightarrow b=x\vee b=y))].$$ (In natural language, $\varphi_K(x,y,z)$ just says "The elements of $z$ are exactly $\{x\}$ and $\{x,y\}$.") There isn't a single way to set up ordered pairs in set theory. The arbitrariness of the choice made here may seem odd but it *is* unavoidable.

Comment: Note that $\mathsf{ZFC}$ (or indeed much less) does prove the crucial facts $$\forall x,y\exists!z[\varphi_K(x,y,z)]$$ *("$\exists!$" is the "unique existence" quantifier; it is just a convenient abbreviation, since $\exists!u\theta(u)$ is equivalent to $\exists u\forall v(\theta(v)\leftrightarrow u=v)$)* and $$\forall x,x',y,y',z[\varphi_K(x,y,z)\wedge\varphi_K(x',y',z)\rightarrow x=x'\wedge y=y'].$$ (And the analogous claims are also $\mathsf{ZFC}$-provable for [the other common ordered pair definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair#Defining_the_ordered_pair_using_set_theory).)

Comment: @NoahSchweber This is not exactly what I want, though. What I am asking for is a way to avoid a binary symbol and to only use a symbol like $z$ or $a$ which isn't a function symbol. Afterwards I want to define the ordered pair with the usual symbol $(x,y)$ to be the object $z$ (or a). However, I don't know if that is possible or not. Basically I want to avoid using a function symbol at first to see if that is possible.

Comment: @MaxH "Avoid a binary symbol..", my approach does exactly that without adding a new function symbol to the language.

Comment: @MaxH I think you've misunderstood this answer and my comments. This approach does not involve adding a function symbol. Look at my formula $\varphi_K$: this is a formula just in the language of set theory. No additional function symbols at all.

Comment: @MaxH To clarify, compare my $\varphi_K(x,y,z)$ with your formula defining intersection $$\eta(x,y,z)\equiv \forall u[u\in z\leftrightarrow u\in x\wedge u\in y]$$ (and note the variable tweaking - my $x,y,z,u$ correspond to your $A,B,C,x$ respectively). You didn't explicitly write down the formula $\eta$, but when you say "Given $x,y$ there is a unique $z$ such that [stuff]" what you're saying is that an appropriate set theory proves $\forall x,y,\exists!z\eta(x,y,z)$. The point is that intersection, unlike pairing, is simple enough that you can accidentally keep the defining formula implicit.